# FileMaker Script Parameter Issue

Tags: parameters, filemaker

So I'm trying to get a `script parameter` set equal to the variable `$SP`, but won't work in my UI in Filemaker. The code I have in my script that's activated when a button is clicked is below:

```
Set Variable [$SP;Value: Get(ScriptParameter)]
Show Custom Dialog [$SP]
Halt Script
```

but nothing displays when i `Show Custom Dialog`, so the code isn't getting the script parameter. I'm also confused as to how to generate a script parameter. Is it only with a drop down menu or can you get a parameter from a regular form box that you can enter text into.

I know this is a basic question, but I'm new to Filemaker and can't seem to find my answer any where else on the web.

Comment: "*the code isn't getting the script parameter*" Or the script parameter is empty, and therefore so is the variable. Have the custom dialog show you the parameter - then you will know for sure.

Comment: After running your test, I'm missing the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set a variable as the parameter of the script, you need to exit the script to do so. Your button has a action of "perform script" select, with which you were able to select the script to be executed or to create a new one. In the "perform script" window, where you select the script to execute, there is a text area in the bottom in which you should put the variable value.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put the column and table name referring to the field as my script parameter next to `Optional script parameter` in the `Specify Script` Menu.

Comment: use GetFieldName ( <table::field> )